# Downloading file from ftp server to local machine

Tags: download, ftp

How should I download file from an ftp server to my local machine using php? Is `curl` good for this?

Comment: You can use `ftp`, `curl`, `wget`, your browser, download manager, etc. It doesn't really matter (but if you want opinion, I prefer `wget`).

Comment: how can i use it inside my php code lines

Comment: "Local Machine" and PHP? PHP runs on web servers, not "local machines". OK, you can run PHP on a local machine, but what's the point? For your local machine, use BASH shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

you can use wget, or curl, from PHP. Be aware that the PHP script will wait for the download to finish. So if the download takes longer than your PHPs max_execution_time, your PHP script will be killed during runtime.

The best way to implement something like this is by doing it asynchronously, that way you don't slow down the execution of the PHP script which is probably supposed to serve a page later.

There are many ways to implement it asynchronously. The cleanest one is probably to use some queue like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ over AMQP. A less clean one, which works as well, would be writing the urls to download into a file, and then implement a cronjob which minutely checkes this file for new urls to download and executes the download.

just some ideas...